# How to properly include Google Maps API with parameters?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been getting the warning `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.` I believe it stems from the fact that I have these two lines in my `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
```

I have tried various ways of including these in one line like `key=MYAPIKEY&libraries=drawing` but it either fails to import either or just the drawing library. Any idea as to how to properly import this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining as `key=MYAPIKEY&amp;libraries=drawing`, Let me know if it works

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&amp;libraries=drawing"></script>
```

Comment: Damn, I thought that would do it, but I got an InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError.

Comment: Try loading libraries first `libraries=drawing&amp;key=MYAPIKEY`

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that.